# Unable to Apply Text Transformation in Jetpack Compose TextStyle

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I'm working on a typography style in Jetpack Compose, and I'm trying to configure it to display all text in uppercase. However, it seems that the TextStyle in Compose does not support text transformation directly.**I need to necessarily configure it by the TextStyle**

I've attempted to use fontFeatureSettings = "c2sc, smcp" to achieve this, but it appears that this modification reduces the text size, rendering it ineffective for my purposes.

[Emulator Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3qQD.png)

Has anyone encountered a solution or workaround for applying an all-uppercase transformation with the textStyle in Jetpack Compose? Your insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
private val BodySmallHigh: TextStyle
    get() {
        return TextStyle(
            fontSize = 12.sp,
            lineHeight = 14.sp,
            color =  Color.Black,
            fontFeatureSettings = "c2sc, smcp"
        )
    }
```

Comment: not currently possible, here is a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227070850